# How do I dynamically change an SVG output in a loop in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: svg, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am trying to make a chess simulation of two random bot players in Jupyter notebooks. To display an SVG image of the chess board, I can perform the following line:
`chess.svg.board(board = board, size = 300)`
This works if I display it in a standalone cell. However, if I try to display this board inside of a loop (so the players can have a display after each time they move), nothing happens. Could someone help me with this? Example below.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What luck! I was trying to visualize the board's dynamic state as well!

```
from IPython.display import display, Image

## Setup board here 
display(board)
```